# Vapor server error

Tags: ubuntu, server, vapor

I am running a vapor server on Ubuntu (16.04.2 TLS) and keep getting this error:

```
**Server error: accept(Socket failed with code 11 ("Resource temporarily unavailable") [acceptFailed])**
```

However, running exactly the same server on OS X, I don't get the error.

Do I have to do anything different on Ubuntu ? Can I inore the error ?

Thanks

Comment: try asking in the slack channel:
http://vapor.team

Answer (score 0):

Can just ignore the error. From vapor developer:

*`You should be able to ignore safely, that's an old issue, I don't remember specifics, but I remember the issue being us misreporting a close as an error - everything closes just fine, it's just our logs are scary`*